# Find rows where the value contains a word from a list of varchar(50)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am collecting data from a t-sql stored procedure to import into c# program. I would like to narrow down the data first.
I have data that has three field that describes the three values that follows them. I need to find only the fields that have one of a dozen keywords in the description.

I was using something that UNION all the fields with values, then

```
...
AND (
        TEXT1234.AccountValue LIKE '%word1%'
     OR TEXT2345.AccountValue LIKE '%word1%'
     OR TEXT3456.AccountValue LIKE '%word1%'

     OR TEXT1234.AccountValue LIKE '%word2%'
     OR TEXT2345.AccountValue LIKE '%word2%'
     OR TEXT3456.AccountValue LIKE '%word2%'

     OR TEXT1234.AccountValue LIKE '%word3%'
     OR TEXT2345.AccountValue LIKE '%word3%'
     OR TEXT3456.AccountValue LIKE '%word3%'
...
```

Now I am trying to do something like this:

```
declare @wordList table (Word varchar(50))
insert into @wordList values ('%word1%'),('%word2%'),('%word3%')...

...
SELECT *
FROM [DB1].dbo.Table_info
WHERE Account = 'TEXT1234'
AND AccountValue LIKE (SELECT * FROM @wordList)
...
```

(This is one of a number of similar UNION pieces. Which is why I would like to use a list of words, to shorten the code, and contain the words in one place in case of future changes.)

OR something Like:

```
SELECT *
FROM [DB1].dbo.Table_info
WHERE Account = 'TEXT1234'
AND AccountValue CONTAINS (SELECT * FROM @wordList)
...
```

Expected output:

```
TEXT1234_Account   TEXT1234_AccountValue       Acct1234   Acct1234_Value
TEXT1234           word3 something something   ACCT1234   48

TEXT3456_Account   TEXT3456_AccountValue        Acct3456   Acct3456_Value
TEXT3456           Something word1 something    ACCT3456   48
```

Please let me know if you need more code to analyze this...
(I am failing at keeping this brief already.)

Comment: I am pretty confused here. In your first query it looks like you have several tables all having the same column name. But later it sounds like that is a value in some column.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. In the first example I used UNION to bring together data and named each TEXT1234, TEXT2345, TEXT3456, etc... In the second example I just show one of the UNIONs to use the list in there instead...

Comment: It isn't clear how you check for _words_. Without handling word breaks the sentence "It was flagrantly violating their civil rights." will match a search for "grant".

Comment: That is correct, the words that I have in my list are actually mostly partial words. For example "consoli" would be in "Consolidation" or "consolidate" etc... The data has some basic restrictions, as well as industry standards for what would be included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use EXISTS:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM [DB1].dbo.Table_info tbl
WHERE tbl.Account = 'TEXT1234'
AND EXISTS
(
    SELECT 0
    FROM @wordList wl
    WHERE tbl.AccountValue LIKE wl.Word
)
```

Comment: Did you know you can use select * inside an exists with zero performance concern? It always throws me when I see select 0 or some other constant. Exists merely checks for the existence of rows. You can even do fun things like where exists(select 1/0...) and it works just fine. :D Still +1 from me for what I can only assume is a good interpretation of the OPs request.

Comment: @SeanLange I know, it's just a minor habit that is just as unimportant as habitually using "*".

Comment: LOL true enough.

Comment: I tested this in a small segment of code. (It will take me awhile to build into the whole project.) But this worked great. Shortens my code and contains the keywords in one place! Thank you!