# How to get all strings that contains any of a given words?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to get all the rows that a property contains any of a list of strings. I am trying in this way:

```
string myWordsToSearch = "word1 word2 word3";
List<string> miLstWords = myWordsToSearch
    .Split(" ")
    .Where(x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x) == false)
    .ToList();
MyDbContext.MyDbSet.Where(x => miLstWords.Any(y => x.MyPropertyInDbSet.Contains(y)));
```

But I get this exception:

> One or more errors occurred. (The LINQ expression  'Where(
>       source: DbSet, 
>       predicate: (s) => Any(
>           source: (Unhandled parameter: __miLstWords_0), 
>           predicate: (y) => MyPropertyInDbSet.Contains(y)))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be
>   translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a
>   call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or
>   ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for
>   more information.

I am using Entity Core 3.0.

Comment: Entity Framework cannot translate `miLstWords.Any` into SQL. How large is `MyDbSet`? Could it make sense to load the database objects into memory first (with `ToList()`) and then you can use the `Where` clause you have? It may not make sense if the database query returns a very large number of results.

Comment: it could be a possible solution, thanks, it is not very big the database, but I would like to know if there is a better solution, for learning too.

Comment: Not completely sure if this will help... I had a similar problem, but I did it in SQL - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58714762/find-rows-where-the-value-contains-a-word-from-a-list-of-varchar50] Check out this solution.

Comment: I think the idea would be something like:  `MyDbContext.MyDbSet.Where(x => miLstWords.Exists(y => x.MyPropertyInDbSet.Contains(y)));'

Comment: What's the type of `MyPropertyInDbSet`?

Comment: Or use this predicatebuilder: https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/

Comment: The classic solution is to build an or expression with a Predicate Builder.

Comment: @Hadi The type it is a own type. Persons with properties Name, Surname... etc.

Comment: @tomg In my case, I am creating a dynamic query according on some parameters that can set the user, so with Tsql would be more work. But it would be an option if I can't find another solution.